# How to add two images in a single table row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am trying to add two images in a single `TableRow`.

I tried to put both the images in the same `TableRow` tag however it is not working. It places them both parallel to the y-axis.

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/i00"
    android:layout_width="79dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/background_board"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/background_board">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stari0
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle" />
```

Comment: put a linear or relative layout inside row, it would help

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android:layout_column="1"` and `android:layout_column="2"` to your ImageView, like this..

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/stari0
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle" />
```

Comment: for more details read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_table_layout.htm